# Regex for : I have a requirement of matching the value request parameter with unicode charcters but it should not allow space

Tags: java, regex, character-properties

Regex for JAVA : I have a requirement of matching the value of a request parameter with unicode charcters but it should not allow space .
Basically a regex which should allow all unicode charcters without space.I tried with all efforts but in vain :(

I got the below regex from ur site but it allows space too, So please help

```
[[a-zA-Z]*[^\\pL\\pM\\p{Nd}\\p{Nl}\\p{Pc}[\\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&amp;&amp;\\p{So}]]*[a-zA-Z]]{1,440}
```

For Example "`Suraj$÷`" should be true but " `Suraj $÷`" this should be false

Comment: What is a "request parameter"?

Comment: Request parameter just like a message content in URL(ex:http:ip:server?messcon="UTF-content"). I should match this content of messcon(URL) with a regex tat will only allow UTF charcters and without space

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^[^\p{whitespace}]+$
```

or

```
^\P{whitespace}+$
```

or, if the Unicode character property `{whitespace}` isn't allowed,

```
^[^\u0009-\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]+$
```

that will match a string that doesn't contain any Unicode white space characters.

Comment: Am using JDK1.4 am getting the below error Unknown charcter category{whitespace}

Comment: Request parameter is a value like message conetnt appende in URL it may contain Only UTF-8 charcters and without space

Comment: @Suraj: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character then make a characters class with all the values for white spaces in unicode

Comment: But should is there not any simple regex that will help me out here

Comment: @Suraj: I'm not a java expert, but it seems JDK1.4 doesn't recognize this character category so you have to explicity fill your character class.

Comment: @Suraj: The Unicode whitespace characters are `[\u0009-\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]`.  Java does not have a property that matches that in Java6 or prior, but in JDK7, the  `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASSES` or `"(?U)"` compilation flag should swap `\s` over to aligning with [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) (and therefore that bracketed character class).  I haven’t checked to make sure it really does what it says it does, though.

Comment: @M42: Java prior to JDK 7 does not have a pattern class that meets the Level 1 requirements of [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support) for Basic Unicode Support. It therefore lacked the `White_Space` property required by [RL 1.2, Properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories). It added some missing props in JDK7, so that might be there now, but it is still a long ways from [RL 2.7, Full Properties](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/tr18-14.html#Full_Properties).

Comment: So using these [\u0009-\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000] values can we :) form a regex tat takes any UTF 8 characters with space. Even if its bit complicated its fine evn i ll try it out here too. Thanks for help in advance

Comment: @Suraj you shouldn’t be thinking about “UTF-8 characters”. You should have already decoded the UTF-8 into abstract Unicode characters. Otherwise the regex engine won’t work right.